# Javafx webengine unable to load localhost sites

Tags: javafx

I have a local server and I am developing a website locally. When I open the web browser and type

```
http://mysite
```

the page loads but when I write:

```
WebView view = new WebView();
WebEngine engine = view.getEnginne();
engine.load ("http://mysite");
```

Nothing loads.
Is it that Javafx web engine cannot load files on localhost or what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I can load pages in `WebView` using `http://localhost:8080` (running Tomcat locally). Does it work if you use a localhost url?

Comment: No not at all. My localhost server is running on Ipv6. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Not sure. Try `http://[::1]:8080/` (edit for a different port if you are not running on port 8080)

Comment: Wow,  that works, but how will I make javafx automatically load sites on ipv6.

Comment: I'm too far outside my expertise area to answer this, but perhaps this has narrowed it down enough for you to edit your question to something a bit more specific. It looks like the JVM is failing to map your web address to the ipv6 loopback address. I have no idea how that works, but I'm sure someone does.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's really appreciated. I will ask a more descriptive question.

Answer (score 0):

If your are running from your local server, insert port as well. 
For example: http://mysite:8080
Updated code given below:

```
WebView view = new WebView();
WebEngine engine = view.getEnginne();
engine.load ("http://mysite:8080");
```